# Filter Range Based on Data Validation Dropdown

Tags: validation, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

I have a Google Sheet that has a cell that I want to use as a drop-down filter for another range within the sheet.
You can take a look at the sheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jsIIpAHPnwLr6P7BAAqWyA0PI5OfGNYlhLok1P5AhHk/edit?usp=sharing).

Cell G11 is the cell that I wish to have the drop-down filter in.
Range B15:H69 is the range that should be filtered upon using this filter.

So, for example - if I select 'Barbarian' in the G11 drop-down the sheet should go from something like this (cut short for size of post sake):
[image]

To something like this:
[image]

I've tried using Named Ranges, using a seperate sheet to filter the data, and a couple other methods I found. Nothing seems to work exactly how I want it to, like in picture #2.

Comment: Do you need all those in-between rows?? Those won't help in stablishing a formula, or at least it will over-complicate something relatively simple

Comment: @Martín I could perhaps try to eliminate them, but there is a picture overlay that I import once the chart is all setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(x),,9^9))&"×​", "×")), " "))
 (QUERY({ROW(Data!A2:D), SORT(Data!A2:D, 3, 0)}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,'♀',Col3,Col4,'♂',Col5 where Col3 = '"&G11&"' label'♀''','♂'''")))
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(x),,9^9))&"×​", "×")), " "))
 (QUERY({ROW(Data!A2:D)-1, SORT(Data!A2:D, 3, 0)}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,'♀',Col3,Col4,'♂',Col5 where 2=2 "&IF(
 REGEXMATCH(G11, "(?i)all|n\/a|^$"),," and Col3 = '"&G11&"'")&" label'♀''','♂'''")))
```

[image]

Comment: When placing this in my B15 cell it is returning either "Error Query completed with an empty output" or "Error Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C15." -- I have opened the Google Sheet to Editor capability, if you're able to add it in there?

Comment: You should delete all your already written values and paste the formula in B15. I've just tried it and it works!

Comment: Dang, amazing. Thank you so much! If I could bother, is there a way to make it go back to 'normal' / showing everything is the drop-down is set to "All" (preferred) or "N/A" (alternative)?

Comment: I also notice the Rank # starts at 2 as opposed to 1. If you look at my image "RAWRBARIAN" is 12 and "JackSparrow" is 13, whereas yours are 1 higher on both.